# How to download multiple files from api in react-native?

Tags: multithreading, react-native, react-native-ios

I know how to download one file using RNFetchBlob, but i need to download multiple files in background for offline access in future..

Also i tried to use React-native-background-fetch, but it's works only for IOS.

Any help is welcome!!

Comment: Any solution for this question?

Comment: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#downloadfileoptions-downloadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promisedownloadresult-

Comment: have u found any solution by now?